# Const behaviour if require fails

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Opening the node repl (v6.6.0) and doing:

```
> const test = require('somethingGuaranteedToFail');
Error: Cannot find module 'somethingGuaranteedToFail'
```

Now the variable `test` can neither be redefined, nor has it been properly initialized.

```
> console.log(typeof test);
ReferenceError: test is not defined
> const test = 1;
TypeError: Identifier 'test' has already been declared
```

It seems to happen with anything that throws an error during assignment, not just require.

I guess the question is, is this expected behaviour? I would have thought the const variable would at least contain the `Error` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess the question is, is this expected behaviour?

Yes. A const cannot be redefined *or* redeclared. `const test` declared it, but failed to define it because an error was raised.

> I would have thought the const variable would at least contain the `Error` object.

`require` does not return an error, it throws one. If you want it, you need to `catch` it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected the behavior. If you throw an exception, the `test` variable will never initialize. This is also the case for something like

```
var getTest;

try {
    getTest = function(){
        return test;
    };

    throw new Error();

    const test = 'a string';
} catch (e){
    // ignore the error
}

getTest();
```

The final call to `getTest` will attempt to access `test`, which was never initialized because the exception caused the string value to never be assigned. It will never be assigned the Error object, because the initialization of `test` is unrelated to the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a bug, but regardless of whether it's intended or not, this behavior can only occur in a REPL environment.

The reason is that, unlike `var`, `const` is *block*-scoped, but if you try to assign the result of a require statement that throws an exception to it (e.g., when the module resolution fails), an exception will be thrown and execution will leave the scope of the block, so the variable falls out of scope. Since you can't stay in the same scope as the variable is defined after an exception is thrown, you cannot redefine a new const variable in the same scope.

However, in the REPL environment, you *don't* leave the same scope when an exception fails, therefore you *can* end up in a situation where a failed const declaration is still in scope, so node refuses to redeclare it.